# Sending multiple image files to mySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, arrays, jpeg

How do I send multiple jpg files, as byte arrays, to my mySQL database with C#?

I have read and understand how to convert image files to byte arrays, but I can only figure out how to use that method for a single image to mySQL as a blob.  My application requires the user to upload at least 2 image files and allows up to 10, while sending information from multiple textBox.  I tried creating an array of byte arrays, but that didn't work.  When I'd reference that array at a specific index during the INSERT string for mySQL, it seemed to store only one byte array and reference that byte array's index rather than the entire byte array that is supposed to be stored in that index.  Below is some of the code showing my attempts:

```
 ///uploading the image and converting it to a byte array
 private void uploadButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        chosenFileTextBox.Text = "No file chosen";
        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(imageFileNameArray[i], FileMode.Open,                         
                 FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            imageFileArray = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
            ///Array of byte arrays
            imageArray[i] = imageFileArray;
            uploadedFilesTextBox.Text += imageFileSafeNameArray[i].ToString() + "\n";
```

The attempt at creating the insert string is below.  The string worked when I sent only one byte array, so I changed the code to attempt 2 byte array's below, with no luck:

```
 //open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?_Date", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dateString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Sex", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = sexString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?FirstName", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = 
                     firstNameString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?LastName", MySqlDbType.Text).Value =
                     lastNameString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?StageName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 
                     stageNameString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Age", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = ageString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Height", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = heightString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?weight", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = weightString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Chest", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = chestString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Waist", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = waistString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Hips", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = hipsString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Dress", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = dressString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Shirt", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = shirtString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Pants", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pantsString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Shoe", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = shoeString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Phone", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = phoneString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?City", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = cityString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?_State", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = stateString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Experience", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 
                     experienceString;
                ///"?Image1" represents Image1 column.  There are 10 columns, but for
                /// this example there are only 2.
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Image1", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = 
                     imageArray.GetValue(0);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Image2", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = 
                     imageArray.GetValue(1);

                //Execute command
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Closed");
            }
```

Comment: I don't have mysql to hand to test this theory, but have you tried assigning imageArray[0] directly to "?Image1" parameter?

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("?Image1", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = (byte[])imageArray.GetValue(0);` help?  You could also try `cmd.Parameters.Add("?Image1", MySqlDbType.Blob, ((byte[])imageArray.GetValue(0)).Length).Value = (byte[])imageArray.GetValue(0);` and if that works, clean up the code.  Lastly, make sure your images size isn't > 65535 otherwise you'll have to use something like a `LongBlob` or something.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at your database structure. In this instance you probably want multiple image columns, or preferably, extract the images into a separate table so that each 'User' can have N images.

Changes might include adding an `Images` table with these columns:

int FK_UserID
blob Image
int ImageType

The FK_UserID is set to the userId, and you can have an ImageType column so that you can have, for example, `ImageType` of 1 for profile photo, etc.
Then you can do a separate `insert` on this table once you have stored your user and know his ID.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually do have multiple rows for images.  I forgot to add them to this example.  I have 10 total.  Do you have an example of this extraction?  When a user uses this web app/form, all of the information they provide in the fields, as well as 2-10 images will be sent to one table.  It will hold all of the information for every user in one table.

Comment: I've added an example.  Doing it that way means that you can save the user, THEN upload images for them in a separate step, knowing their user id.  Have a look at uploading asynchronously using something like Uploadify.

Comment: I don't know if my question is clear, because I asked another programmer what I asked up here and he suggested the same thing as you did in your example.  My problem is not the uploading or saving to the DB part.  I will use a switch statement depending on how many images are uploaded.  Also, I have the 10 Blob columns of my DB set to null as default, so that will be fine.  My real issue here is that I cannot get my program to create 10 byte arrays to send over to the DBconnect Class.  I tried making an array of byte arrays, but it didn't work.  My friend reccomended lists.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for answering btw.  Also, would you mind bumping my question up?  IDK if any one else is seeing it.